# Как передать в функцию статический двумерный массив?

Tags: c++, массивы

Функция транспонирует матрицу `m[rows][cols]`. Неизвестно, каким именно способом выделялась память под матрицу `m[][]`.

Как в таком случае правильно обрабатывать статические массивы (формат вызова функции измениться не должен)?

> int a[rows][cols] = {...}; //error: cannot convert 'int (*)[3]' to
>   'const int* const*' for argument '1'

```
int ** transpose(const int * const * m, unsigned rows, unsigned cols)
{
    // Выделение памяти под транспонированную матрицу
    int ** mt = create_array2d(cols, rows);

    // Заполнение транспонированной матрицы
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
        for(unsigned j = 0; j < cols; ++j)
            mt[j][i] = m[i][j];

    // Освобождение памяти, выделенной под исходную матрицу
    free_array2d(m, rows, cols);
    m = NULL;

    return mt;
}
```

Comment: Решения этой проблемы с одномерными массивами уже видел, но подходящего под этот случай не нашел.

Comment: вы знаете размеры массива?

Comment: @BanyRule  Вы не сможете преобразовать двумерный массив к типу const int * const * .   Вы можете дополнительно к вашей функции написать шаблонную функцию для двумерных массивов.

Comment: Нет, именно поэтому вариант с m[][cols] не подойдёт.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Что-то в духе template<typename T, size_t col> T process(T a[][col], size_t row) ?

Comment: @BanyRule Можете таким образом объявить.

Comment: @BanyRule, вы пытаетесь передать *непрерывный двумерный массив* в функцию, которая ожидает *массив массивов*.

Comment: @Arhad я понимаю различия в представлении в памяти динамических и статических массивов, просто наверняка есть какой-то костыль, решающий эту проблему.

Comment: @BanyRule, что вы подразумеваете под *статическими* массивами? Организация (jagged/сплошной) и статичность – это совершенно ортогональные понятия.

Comment: @Arhad да, неправильно выразился. Под статическим я имел ввиду массив созданный на стеке, а под динамическим - созданный через new []

Comment: Ну так ошибка времени компиляции возникает не из-за попытки удалить массив, а из-за несовпадения *передаваемого извне* и *ожидаемого функцией* видов массивов. сначала согласуйте типы (оба должны работать либо с jagged, либо с цельным массивом).

Comment: А касательно корректного освобождения – передавайте в функцию помимо массива ещё и указатель на функцию по его удалению (с сигнатурой, к примеру, `void (*deleter)(int* /* array_ptr */)`, типа виртуальных деструкторов в C++). Для стековых массивов этот указатель будет вести на пустую функцию-заглушку, а для массивов на куче – вызывать `free` либо `delete[]`. Вызывающая нас сторона знает способ создания передаваемого массива, а потому способна передать нам и корректный указатель. **Но по хорошему, уничтожать массив должен его владелец, то есть вызывающая сторона после возврата из `transpose`**.

Comment: Придется перед вызовом сформировать одномерный массив указателей на строки статического двумерного.

Comment: @avp всё несколько хуже. У меня нет возможности контролировать то, как передают значения. Я могу редактировать только саму функцию         transose

Comment: @Arhad оказывается освобождение памяти и в правду можно было оставить на совести владельца массива. Вынесите комментарий в ответы, тогда я смогу поставить "+".

Answer (score 1):

Для решения такой задачи вам нужно использовать [Function overloading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_overloading) или по русски [перегрузку функций](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%80_%D0%B8_%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B9).

В двух словах, если у нескольких функций одинаковое имя, но разный набор аргументов (в т.ч. их типов), то такие функции называются *перегруженными*.

В своей программе на  C++ вам достаточно дописать вот такую реализацию `transpose`:

```
int **transpose (int *a, unsigned rows, unsigned cols)
{
  int ** mt = create_array2d(cols, rows); 

  for(unsigned i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
    for(unsigned j = 0; j < cols; ++j)
      mt[j][i] = a[i * cols + j];

  // обратите внимание, память статической (или в стеке) матрицы мы не освобождаем
  return mt;
}
```

и при таком вызове из "main":

```
  int a[10][20], *t;
  ...
  t = transpose(&a[0][0], 10, 20);
```

компилятор вызовет ее, а при таком вызове:

```
  int **m = create_array2d(20, 10);
  ...
  t = transpose(m, 10, 20);
```

ваш первоначальный вариант `transpose()`.

Только старайтесь не злоупотреблять перегрузкой, поскольку она делает программу в целом менее понятной (по крайней мере не ее автором).

Answer (score 1):

Массив, объявленный как

```
int a[rows][cols]
```

в принципе не совместим с параметром функции, объявленным как

```
const int * const * m
```

поэтому никакого способа вызвать эту функцию напрямую для такого массива не существует.

Если вы хотите выполнить такой вызов, то вам придется сначала выполнить конверсию представлений, т.е. организовать промежуточный временный "индексный" массив

```
int *a_rows[rows] = { a[0], a[1], a[2], /* и т.д. */ };
```

и затем вызывать именно

```
transpose(a_rows, rows, cols);
```

Однако тот факт, что внутри функции `transpose` выполняется уничтожение исходного массива через вызов `free_array2d`, говорит о том, что сама идея вызова `transpose` для массива `int a[rows][cols]` - порочна и бессмысленна.

Ваша функция `transpose` в принципе не предназначена для работы с такими массивами. Функция предназначена только для работы с массивами, созданными через функцию `create_array2d`. Ей и пользуйтесь.