# Вывод массива строк

Tags: c, строки, функции, указатели

Хочу создать функцию для вывода содержимого массива. При запуске крашится программа... Вот код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <string.h>
#define SIZE 10
#define N 40
void show(char **,int);
int main(void)
{
  setlocale(LC_ALL,"RUS");
  char str[SIZE][N];
  int k=0;
  char *comp;
  int choise;
  printf("Введите до 10 строк\n");
  while(k<SIZE&&fgets(str[k],N,stdin)!=NULL)
  {
    comp=str[k];
    while(*comp!='\n'&&*comp!='\0')
      comp++;
    if(*comp=='\0')
      while(getchar()!='\n')
        continue;
    else
      *comp='\0';
    k++;
  }
 show(str,k);
 return 0;
}
void show(char **str,int k)
{
  int i=0;
  int g;
  while(i++<k)
    puts(*str++);
}
```

Comment: Почему вы пытаетесь передавать двумерный массив туда, где требуется `char **`? Вам компилятор ясно сказал, что так делать нельзя. Неудивительно, что все крашится.

Comment: @AnT, а как мне нужно изменить код, чтобы передать двумерный массив?

Comment: Изменить код можно по-разному. Можно сделать `void show(char str[][N], int k)`. А можно поступить как в https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/614509/182825

Comment: @AnT, да, теперь действительно ничего не крашится. А почему вариант с **str не работает?

Comment: А почему он должен работать? Массив `char [N][M]` и указатель `char **` ничего общего не имеют. По ссылке уже написано.

Comment: @AnT, ну ведь я передаю в качестве аргумента имя массива. Имя массива - это адрес его первого элемента, т.е. *str дает значение первого элемента(который является строкой), следовательно puts(*str) должен вывести эту строку.

Comment: Ваша функция требует на вход `char **` -- это массив *указателей* на строки, а не массив строк. А вы ей на вход пихали `char [N][M]` - массив строк. "Массив строк" и "массив указателей на строки" - это соверешенно разные вещи. И нет, имя массива - это НЕ указатель на его первый элемент. Имя массива может лишь *приводиться* к указателю на элемент.