# Как используется адресная арифметика с многомерным массивом?

Tags: c

Интересуюсь, как организовать инициализацию двумерного массива с помощью указателей.

```
int main(){
    float a[N][N];
    int n;

    clrscr();

    n = setsize(n);

    arndom(a, n);

    getch();
    return 0;
}

void arndom(float **array, int size){
     float **str_scan, *stol_scan;

     srand(time(NULL));

     printf("Source array:\n");

     for(str_scan = array; str_scan < &array[size][size]; str_scan++){
     for(stol_scan = *str_scan; stol_scan < &array[str_scan - array][size]; stol_scan++){
         stol_scan = rand() % -99,9 - 99,9;
         printf("%.2f ", *stol_scan);
     }
     printf("\n");
     }
}
```

Comment: `float **array` это массив указателей, а не двумерный массив

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/942951/Вывод-массива-строк

Answer (score 0):

**Многомерный массив - `int a[N][M];`**

Хорошо использовать когда размер известен на этапе компиляции.
Пример:

```
int a[2][3];
int i, j;
for (i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        a[i][j] = (i + 1) * (j + 1);
}

for (i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        printf("%d ", a[i][j]);
    printf("\n");
}
```

Память под такой массив освобождается автоматически после завершения выполнения блока кода где он был обьявлен.

**Массив указателей на указатель - `int ** a;`**

Хорошо использовать когда размер массива не известен на этапе компиляции. Пример:

```
int ** a;
int N = 2, M = 3; //Допустим эти значения считываются откуда то во время работы программы... 
int i, j;

a = calloc(N, sizeof(int*)); //выделение массива указателей.
for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    a[i] = calloc(M, sizeof(int)); //выделение массива int'ов, в элементе массива указателей. 


for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < M; j++)
        a[i][j] = (i + 1) * (j + 1);
}

for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < M; j++)
        printf("%d ", a[i][j]);
    printf("\n");
}

for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
     free(a[i]); //освобождение массива int'ов в массиве указателей 
}
free(a); //осовобождения массива указателей
```